# Cannot get the most basic click event binding to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript, and I have tried to debug as much as I can but I still cannot figure why I cannot get the alert "Event 1" to show up when I click on text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


    $("#id").bind("click", function() {
      alert("Event 1");
    });

  </script>

  <body>
  <div class="foo" id="id">Click</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("#id").click(function(e) { ... }`

Comment: @nilobarp irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to ensure that you only bind to the element once the page has loaded, and the element is therefore accessible. This can be done by wrapping your existing jQuery in a **[`$(document).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)**, as can be seen in the following working example.

Also, note that **[`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)** has been deprecated as of jQuery 3.0, and you should use **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead. Note that the elements that you target with `.on` must exist at the time that you make the call to them:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on()

If your target element is **not** visible in the DOM on page load, you can use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** to bind to an element that **is** visible on page load, and then **delegate** that functionality to the target.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id").on("click", function() {
      alert("Event 1");
    });
  });
</script>

<body>
  <div class="foo" id="id">Click</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7

Comment: Yep; I've just updated my answer to mention this, and recommend using `.on()` instead :)